# How to build a Facebook app with PHP that shows albums?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to build a Facebook web application that uses the graph API to show only the albums of a specific user. That user is always the same, and I know his credentials.

My code so far:

```
$this->facebook->api("username/albums?access_token=" . $this->access_token);
```

But I get the following exception:

```
[error] => Array
(
    [message] => A user access token is required to request this resource.
    [type] => OAuthException
    [code] => 102
)
```

I need to generate an `acces_token` that lives forever and is able to retrieve this information, because right now I can only access public data. Where do I have to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a registered app you can generate an app access token which is always valid.

Use this URL to get your access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &grant_type=client_credentials
```

You can find the App id and App secret on your apps page.
Please note that the albums and/or photos you see depend on the privacy settings of the albums/photo/

Comment: This doesn't work, same exception. How does facebook know what the correct user is? ps. eindelijk een Nederlander :D

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Should have checked more closely. The error message states it already, you need a **user** access token. It is impossible to generate a user token that will never expire. ps. en jawel! ;)

Comment: According to facebook this only works until oktober. Then they will only use acces_tokens that work for 60 days. And how do i generate one?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ + https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: What you mean only applies to the `offline_access` permission. For obtaining a user access token for the user that visits your app check this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and more specifically probably this one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side or this one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side What are you trying to do exactly? You could also drop me a note in my e-mail, see profile.