# Show my own Facebook's user albums on my PHP site

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

My question is almost the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110934/how-to-build-a-facebook-app-with-php-that-shows-albums), but I can't find the answer there.

I just want to show my Facebook albums on a PHP page.

I know that for my site to access a Facebook user's info, I need an Access Token. As the username and password will always be the same, I'd like that my site (or app) could send these informations directly to Facebook and get an Access Token, without any user interaction. I've read this process as a [OAuth Username and Password Flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-05#section-3.8).

Is it possible with Facebook?

Comment: Maybe using cURL to fetch `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I do not believe has an OAuth Username and Password Flow.

Each flow by Facebook requires the user to manually grant the app access.